# PHP 7: Dying unexpectedly without error message

Tags: php, error-handling

I have what it must be a very simple method, but it's unexpectedly diying at 'return' line and not throwing any errors. I already enabled error reporting E_All; I already checked apache error_log;

What am I missing?

```
public function get_by_state_id(int $state_id){
    $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'foo');
    $query = "
        SELECT *
        FROM {$this->table}
        WHERE state_id = ?
        ORDER BY name";
    if($stmt = $db->prepare($query)){
        $stmt->bind_param('i',$state_id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $res = $stmt->get_result();

        $rows = [];

        while($obj = $res->fetch_object()){
            $rows[] = $obj;
        }

        return $rows;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know it's dying and not just returning anything? Add an else statement for when the prepare fails, and return something else, or just return an empty array.

Comment: Have you tried this: [How to enable MySQLi exception mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)

Comment: @anyber I know it cause I'm debugging and I see that the array has values

Comment: @Dharman I had not, but now I did it and still not getting any message :(

Comment: If you are debugging, where you able to check the values of `$rows` in the debugger? Have you noticed any pattern or anything special about it?

Comment: @Dharman Nothing special. It just save the values into $rows as if evereyhing is about to be just fine, but then it dies.

Comment: Would you be able to prepare a minimal set of data from that data for which it dumps. I would like to try to reproduce this on my machine. You can use `var_export()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194716/discussion-between-uriel-and-dharman).

Comment: How are you call this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Dharman point me out: the error was due to be echoing unscaped utf8 chars.

It was solved adding this right after the mysql connection:

```
$db->set_charset('utf8mb4');
```

He also provided a link to read more about it: [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)